# Does SOLR support percolation

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

ElasticSearch has percolator for prospective search. Does SOLR have a similar feature where you define your query upfront? If not, is there an effective way of implementing this myself on top of the existing SOLR features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's listed as an open new feature, [SOLR-4587](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4587), on Solr JIRA but it doesn't seem like any work has started on it yet.

There is a link in the comments there to a separate project called [Luwak](https://github.com/flaxsearch/luwak) that seems to implement some features similar to percolator.

Answer (score 6):

besides what BunkerMentality said, it is not hard to build your own percolator, what you need:

1. Are the queries you want to run easy to model on Lucene only syntax? if so you are good, if not, you need to convert them to Lucene only. Built them, and keep them in memory as Lucene queries
2. When a doc arrives:
3. build a MemoryIndex containing only that single doc
4. run all your queries on the index

I have done this for a system ingesting millions docs a day and it worked fine.

Comment: Is it possible to use plugins like Kuromoji with Lucene in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If it is still relevant, you can use [this](https://github.com/SOLR4189/solcolator)

It's SOLR Update Processor that based on Luwak